# Jones representation of Unpolarized light

Tags: astrophysics, polarization

What is the Jones matrix representation of completely unpolarized light?

Context : Majority of astrophysical sources' emission is totally unpolarized or partially polarized. I need to know the representation of Unpolarized light to investigate the induced instrumental polarization by a telescope.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Jones vector can only deal with fully polarised light.

If you want to deal with unpolarised or partially polarised light (and polarised light) then the Stokes vector should be used.